# Creating new personal table for user in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Can anyone assist me in solving the problem below.

- I have a table in sqlalchemy called 'Person'.
- Each person has a unique 'name'.
- 'Person' table has a relationship to 'Pet' table based on the 'name' field.

I would like everyone in the Person table have the possibility to have a pet with the same name of somebody else, but one person cannot have two pets with the same name, but I am not sure how to model/code that.

Person: Zbyszek

1. Pet: Flufi - age: 3
2. Pet: Chili - age: 2

Person: Jon

1. Pet: Chili - age: 4

code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///sql1.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    pets = db.relationship('Pet', backref='owner')
    
class Pet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

Comment: Is the problem that what you displayed doesn't work? Or that you want to add the functionality that 'Zbyszek' can't have another pet named 'Flufi' ?

Comment: exactly, I wish Zbyszek could have only one pet with a given name

Comment: All right added support for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the `unique=True` tag on the pets if there can be more than one pet with that name, even if they belong to different people. There is no problem in removing it and I don't see why you would need the name to be unique anyway since you obviously want the possibilty of multiple pets with the same name. Since the ID of the pet is unique the name doesn't have to be.

If you now want only one of each pet name available to one person, you to set that as a table argument for the pet. So that no two pets with the same owner can also have the same name.

Updated pet class:

```
class Pet(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('owner_id ', 'name', name='owner_pet_uc'),)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

Comment: its only example, my project is more complicated. I want that every person can have pet whit this same name but one person can have only one pet whit this name.

Comment: Updated the answer to add a unique constraint for the pet name and owner id ;)

Comment: Remember to accept as answer if it was what you were looking for :)

Comment: Thank you. it works. Can you tell me if i can give random name in db.UniqueConstraint?? And when i tested this, i have errors whit info that they are unique. How to track this error in aplication??

Comment: Don't fully understand what you're asking, I recommend creating a new question!